# Distance between clusters in d3 multi foci force layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to understand this example of a multi-foci force layout...

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1804919

It contains a "padding" variable (which defines the distance between nodes in each cluster), but I'm really struggling to see where the definition of the distances between clusters comes from - a combination of gravity and charge maybe?!

For example, if you wanted to double the distance between the clusters how could you achieve that?  I've played with the customisable values in the example to no avail so would really appreciate any help from anyone.  Thanks!

Comment: The global charge and gravity parameters of the layout are both set to zero in this case.  The layout is driven by the tick function, which is called by force before every animation frame of the browser (time permitting) and a custom `gravity` function is applied to each node to pull them toward their focii.  The `collision` function, using `padding` as minimum distance between nodes, is keeping them apart.  Try setting charge to a negative number to push the nodes apart...

Comment: The number of clusters is `m` and they are evenly distributed using the `x` scale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `m` to a smaller value will increase the distance between clusters. This is the `domain` for the orginal scale `x` which is used to initialise the cx values on the elements of the nodes array.
Calling them `cx` and `cy` is a little bit confusing because they are not the `cx` and `cy` attributes of the circles.
The `cx` value for each node is is determined by feeding a random integer into the ordinal scale `x` By the statement `cx: x(i)`.
The circles are moved toward the focii by calling `gravity` every tick (animation frame). This is done in the following statement...

```
d.x += (d.cx - d.x)*alpha
```

`alpha` is fixed at 0.5 in the `tick` function when calling `gravity`, but there is another `alpha` which could also be used. It's a variable maintained by the `force` object which is initially set to 0.1 before the first tick, and reduced by 1% every tick. It's passed to the tick function as `e.alpha`, so you could also try passing this value into the gravity function instead of a constant 0.5. The effect will be to cause the nodes to "cool down" more and more gradually until they stop.

Comment: Thanks for the response Cool Blue! So the cluster distance is defined by  x by spreading the number of clusters across the canvas.  I was hoping to control things more directly than that, and just stumbled across this example which includes a separate clusterPadding variable: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7881887.  I'm now trying to figure out how to reconcile the 2 lines in the collide function that include clusterPadding - "var r = d.radius + maxRadius + Math.max(padding, clusterPadding)" and "r = d.radius + quad.point.radius + (d.cluster === quad.point.cluster ? padding : clusterPadding);"

Comment: p.s. in the multi-foci example those lines are "var r = d.radius + maxRadius + padding" and "r = d.radius + quad.point.radius + (d.color !== quad.point.color) * padding;"

Comment: @d3wannabe the padding is just added to the radius when calculating collisions, it is different for same-colour and different-colour interactions.  After the collision has been resolved, it's the distance between the nodes...